# A question on maximal monotone operators

Tags: functional-analysis, monotone-operator-theory

> **Definition**: Let $H$ a Hilbert space. An unbounded linear operator $A: D(A) \subseteq H \to H$ is said to be *monotone* if it satisfies
>   $$\forall v \in D(A),\ (Av, v) \ge 0 $$
>
> It is called *maximal monotone* if, in addition, $R(I + A) = H$, i.e.,
>   $\forall f \in H,\ \exists  u \in D(A) \text{ such that }u + Au = f$

If $A $ is maximal monotone then $\lambda A $ is also maximal monotone for every
$\lambda > 0$.

However, if $A$ and $B$ are maximal monotone operators, then $A + B$, defined
on $D(A) \cap D(B)$, need not be maximal monotone. Why?

Comment: A hint might be to consider the possible sizes of $D(A) \cap D(B)$.

Comment: it is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonable example is defined on $X=L^{2}[0,\pi]$. Let $H^{2}[0,\pi]$ be the subspace of $X$ consisting of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^{2}$ for which $f',f'' \in L^{2}$. Define $A$ and $B$ to be $-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on their respective domains
$$
          \mathcal{D}(A)= \{ f \in H^{2} : f(0)=f(\pi) = 0 \},\\
          \mathcal{D}(B) = \{ f \in H^{2} : f'(0)=f'(\pi)=0 \}.
$$
$A$ and $B$ are selfadjoint which satisfy
$$
            (Af,f) \ge 0,\;\;\; f \in \mathcal{D}(A), \\
            (Bf,f) \ge 0, \;\;\; f \in \mathcal{D}(B).
$$
However the restriction of $A+B$ to $\mathcal{D}(A)\cap\mathcal{D}(B)$ is not selfadjoint, and $A+B+I$ is not surjective because that would mean it would be possible to solve the following for all $g \in L^{2}$:
$$
                   -2f''+f = g,\\
                    f(0)=f'(0) = 0,\\
                    f(\pi)=f'(\pi) = 0.
$$
That cannot happen for all $g$.

Comment: $A$ and $ B$ are selfadjoint why?

Comment: and why $A+B$ to $D(A)∩D(B)$ is not selfadjoint ?

Comment: @jafar Let $L=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on twice absolutely continuous $f \in L^{2}[0,\pi]$ for which $f''\in L^{2}[0,\pi]$. The restriction $L_{\alpha,\beta}$ of $L$ to the domain $f \in \mathcal{D}(L)$ for which $\cos\alpha f(0)+\sin\alpha f'(0)=0$ and $\cos\beta f(\pi)+\sin\beta f'(\pi)=0$ is selfadjoint, and has a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions. You can construct a Green function to see that. Those are the only selfadjoint restrictions of $L$ with separated endpoint conditions. The intersection of graphs of two different such operators cannot be selfadjoint.

Comment: @jafar The graph $\mathcal{D}(L^{\star})$ is the restriction of $L$ to $f\in\mathcal{D}(L)$ for which $f(0)=f'(0)=f(\pi)=f'(\pi)=0$. So $\mathcal{D}(L^{\star})/\mathcal{D}(L)$ is 4-dimensional. A selfadjoint restriction $L_{r}$ of $L$ must have a graph of co-dimension $2$; so the intersection of two different ones cannot be selfadjoint.